# Why does a SwiftUI Rectangle with opacity 0.0 render a grey rectangle on a transparent NSWindow?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

I have a transparent `NSWindow` containing a Grid of `Rectangles` whose opacity can be toggled. When the opacity is 0.0 a grey rectangle is rendered (see image) where I would expect to see an empty space.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried modifying the background colour to `Color.clear` in all the parent views (littered throughout this code), but suspect the cause lies elsewhere - perhaps due to the way transparent windows behave, as there also appear to be drop shadows and outlines etc.

**NOTE:** Toggling between opacity 1.0 and 0.0 behaves slightly differently, so wondered if a view gets backed if the opacity is < 1.0 || > 0.0?

[image: screenshot]

My target is `macOS 11.1`

My `NSWindow` is constructed thus:

```
class TransparentWindow: NSWindow {

    init(contentRect: NSRect, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: [.borderless, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        ignoresMouseEvents = true
        titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        titleVisibility = .hidden
        isOpaque = false
        backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        level = .floating
        isMovable = false
        isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        orderFront(nil)

        toolbar?.isVisible = false
        
        // Hide the traffic icons (standard close, minimize, maximize buttons)
        standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        
        styleMask.insert(NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView)
    }
}
```

And views are roughly as follows:

```
struct GridView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appStore : AppStore

    var body: some View {
        let columns: [GridItem] =
            Array(repeating: .init(.fixed(size), spacing: spacing), count: cols)
                
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing) {
            ForEach(appStore.items) { item in
                GridItemView(item: item)
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .border(Color.clear, width: 0.0)

            }
        }.padding(0)
        .fixedSize()
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
}

struct GridItemView : View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appStore : AppStore
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State var opacity = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .onReceive(appStore.$frame) { frame in
                    let newFrame = calculateItemRect(
                        frame: frame,
                        crop: geometry.frame(in: .global)
                    )
                    
                    if (!newFrame.equalTo(item.frame)) {
                        item.frame = newFrame
                    }
                }.onReceive(item.$toggle) { toggle in
                    if toggle {
                        opacity = 0.0
            
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                            opacity = 0.5
                            item.toggle = false
                        }
                    }
                }.opacity(opacity)
        }.background(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set the `hasShadow` property to `false` on the `NSWindow` instance:

```
class TransparentWindow: NSWindow {

        // ...
        hasShadow = false
        ignoresMouseEvents = true
        // ...
    }
}
```